# SQL Server get maximum mdf file size

Tags: sql-server

I have a growth limit in sql server which I set for my databases with the statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE [" + databaseName + "] 
MODIFY FILE (NAME=dataFile,MAXSIZE = " + newSize + "MB)";
```

How can I fetch the size that I set for the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
select db.name as [db_name], mf.name, mf.max_size
from sys.master_files mf
JOIN sys.databases db ON mf.database_id = db.database_id
order by db.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the following stored procedure on the net ([Find SQL Server data and log files that are almost out of space](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2359/find-sql-server-data-and-log-files-that-are-almost-out-of-space/)).

Run it with `EXEC usp_get_db_files_near_maxsize <somepercentage>` to find all database files, both data and log, that are within `<somepercentage>` of being filled only for files where you have set a maximum size.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_get_db_files_near_maxsize (@nearMaxSizePct DECIMAL (5,1) = 10.0)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE ##ALL_DB_Files (
dbname SYSNAME,
fileid smallint,
groupid smallint,
[size] INT NOT NULL,
[maxsize] INT NOT NULL,
growth INT NOT NULL,
status INT,
perf INT,
[name] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
[filename] NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL)

-- loop over all databases and collect the information from sysfiles
-- to the ALL_DB_Files tables using the sp_MsForEachDB system procedure
EXEC sp_MsForEachDB
@command1='use [$];Insert into ##ALL_DB_Files select db_name(), * from sysfiles',
@replacechar = '$'

-- output the results
SELECT
[dbname] AS DatabaseName,
[name] AS dbFileLogicalName,
[filename] AS dbFilePhysicalFilePath,
ROUND(size * CONVERT(FLOAT,8) / 1024,0) AS ActualSizeMB,
ROUND(maxsize * CONVERT(FLOAT,8) / 1024,0) AS MaxRestrictedSizeMB,
ROUND(maxsize * CONVERT(FLOAT,8) / 1024,0) - ROUND(size * CONVERT(FLOAT,8) / 1024,0) AS SpaceLeftMB
FROM ##ALL_DB_Files
WHERE maxsize > -1 AND -- skip db files that have no max size
([maxsize] - [size]) * 1.0 < 0.01 * @nearMaxSizePct * [maxsize] -- find db files within percentage
ORDER BY 6

DROP TABLE ##ALL_DB_Files

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```